How to calculate BLEU score for CodeT5 on CONCODE when test.json lacks code labels?
I am using CodeT5 for text-to-code generation on the CONCODE dataset, as introduced in Microsoft's CodeXGLUE repository. The dataset's test.json file is missing the "code" labels, which are needed for evaluation. After fine-tuning the model, how can I calculate the BLEU score or evaluate its performance without these labels? Is there a standard method for handling this scenario?
Thank you.
I know by splitting the train.json I can get the new test.json, but I want to know if there's any standard method for it.
I want to replicate "CodeT5: Identifier-aware Unified Pre-trained Encoder-Decoder Models for Code Understanding and Generation" as similar as possible!
